# Identifying Missing or Redundant Classes in Domain Model

Tags: oop, model, uml, domain-driven-design, analysis

I am currently working on a school assignment that requires me to identify missing or redundant classes in a domain model based on a given scenario. Unfortunately, I am having some difficulty with this task and would really appreciate some help.

Below is the scenario and domain model that I have been given:

> Scenario:
> The following specification describes how a user logs in to a web site.
>
> Basic Flow:
> The login box is displayed.
> The user enters userid and password.
> The login box disappears and the next page is displayed.
>
> Alternative Flows:
> 3a. Userid and password don't match.
> Login box remains and the user is informed that userid or password was wrong.

Domain Model After Noun Identification:

[User] - [Login Box] - [Next Page]

Based on this information, I have attempted to identify any missing or redundant classes in the domain model. However, I am not sure if my analysis is correct. Here is my attempt:

1. Missing classes:

   I think there may be some missing classes in the domain model, such as "Authentication" or "Session Management". These classes are important for handling user authentication and maintaining a user's session after logging in.
2. Redundant classes:

   I think the "Login Box" class may be redundant as it is only used in the Basic Flow of the scenario. Once the user logs in, the login box disappears and is no longer relevant.
3. Classes to be turned into attributes:

   I don't think any of the classes in the domain model need to be turned into attributes.

I would really appreciate it if someone could take a look at my analysis and let me know if I am on the right track. If there are any missing or redundant classes that I have not identified, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[Domain model after noun identification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AryNW.png):

[image]

Comment: Password as a class???

Comment: @qwerty_so Well, it's not necessary to have "Password" as a separate class in the domain model, as it can be an attribute of the "User" class. However, if the system has more complex password requirements or security measures, then it may make sense to have a separate class to handle password validation and management. It ultimately depends on the specific requirements and complexity of the system being modeled.

Comment: Fail. I simply refuse to sign up with companies that have password as class and end up with "must have 3 to 8 chars not double one upper and one  special". A password is a secret hard to guess. Only if you deal with that in a miltitary or so domain you can make it a science.

Comment: Why is this tagged `dns` (Domain Name System)?

Answer (score 2):

#### Flaw in the exercise narrative: domain or solution?

First of all, whatever your teacher told you, the narrative does not describe a domain. Instead, it describes a solution:

- The domain model would refer to identity,  authentication, user account, business rules and constraints. There's btw a whole ISO standard about this topic.
- The solution describes the behavior of a particular user interface (boxes that appear/disappear, fields that need to be filled) on the top of the domain.

#### Overcoming the flaws: focusing on domain

The domain is partially hidden behind the solution. So identifying nouns and nominal groups is not sufficient: `User`, (act of) `Logging In`, `Website`, `Login box`, `UserId`, `Password`, `Entering fields` (userid, password), (next) `Page`, `Disappearing`, `Displaying` (a page), `Matching` (passwords).

You need to eliminate user-interface elements, as well as solution dependent terms (e.g. you could do a native mobile app without website and pages): `User`, (act of) `Logging In`, <strike>`Website`</strike>, <strike>`Login box`</strike>, `UserId`, `Password`, <strike>`Entering fields` (userid, password)</strike>, <strike>(next) `Page`</strike>, <strike>`Disappearing`</strike>, <strike>`Displaying` (a page)</strike>, `Matching` (passwords).

In reality, **you cannot identify the domain model from *this* scenario without prior knowledge** to identify essential missing elements not described:

- User are persons who have an `Identity`, but they are usually represented by a `User Account`
- Logging in is a specific form of `Authentication`.  Other exists such as biometric means, identity certificates, SSO tokens, etc.
- Authentication is needed for `Access control`

#### Not every identified noun should be a class

Last but not least, once you have identified the domain elements, you need to keep in mind that they are classifiers and not necessarily classes, in other words, they could be elements that belong to a class that do not make sense in isolation, for example:

- they could be data types (like a class, but solely identified by their value, like password, if you want to add some operations such as checking strength, etc...)
- they could be attributes of a given datatype (e.g. a userid could be a string attribute)
- they could be properties (e.g a class that could be associated to another one that owns the end of the association, or an attribute)
- they could be operations, for which a verb naming would be better (`matchPasswords()` instead of `Matching`)

#### How to find missing classes?

You need to complete your identification by drawing the identified associations between the classes. Sometimes it makes no sense to associate class candidates. This is often the symptom of a missing class:

- Can a `Password` be directly associated with a `User`? Yes, but it makes no sense without `UserId`.  So either the two elements are properties of `User`, or there is a missing class:  User being the identified person, and UserAccount being a class having a userid and a password.

#### Conclusion: fiction vs. reality

*Domain Model After Noun* is an appealing concept.  But it is very theoretical and doomed to fail in practice, because of synonyms, of subtle differences between related concepts, of incompleteness in the narratives,  of inconsistencies in the requirements, of lack of creativity.

The key to the domain model, is to understand the domain and its concepts.  It's exactly as reading a novel:  You don't understand a novel just by analysing the words, but you read, you imagine the characters and the scene,  and you gradually refine this understanding.  This is how you do in reality:  listen carefully to the domain experts,  understand what they say,  model your understanding,  discuss it with the experts and refine it until no change is needed anymore.